# VMware Ubuntu 20.04 Piix4_SMBus: 000:00:07.3: Host SMBus controller bus not enabled

Tags: boot, vmware

I'm using Ubuntu as virtual machine on VMware player. I ran into a problem with Piix4_SMBus today. I have tried to solve this problem in different ways. I increased the disk space. I added `i2c-piix4` and `i2c_piix4`, `intel_powerclamp` to the blacklist, ran `update-initramfs -u -k all`, ran clean (was only able to run once). None of these things helped. Maybe it's space related, since I was getting the message about not enough disk space before. Please help with a solution to this problem. I really need to at least get the files out of the desktop.

I did a memory scan with df -h. /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root and /sda3/ take up the most space. How can I delete the unnecessary files, and try to start the system?